# How to have two either or owner for a data in table django?

Tags: django

Lets say I have a table,

```
Class Application:
      owner = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
      dob =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Basically, a student can make a application ! That's how the above on linked, now lets say I have user type called "Agents". I also want them to make application, how to achieve that ?

Should i create a new field named

```
      employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Can i have two onetoone field ? Or it should be foriegnField ? How to manage to store when students applies and also when employee applies ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way will be just to use the User model.something like this

```
Class Application:
      owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
      dob =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
```